# Angular subscription fires only once

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-services, behaviorsubject

Trying to make subscription with Behaviour Subject on click listener and get only empty object from the service on the first load of the component where subscription is made;

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.shareDataService.dataUpdate$.subscribe(success =>{
      this.data = success;
    })
  }
```

I've tried with observable and async pipe and the result is the same. Service is `providedIn: 'root'`. If subscription is in `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {}` lifecycle hook subscription is fired on every click, but there is always empty object.

I tried to reproduce it on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrabjt) and everything works fine. Object is sent from `object-sender` component to the service;

```
this.shareDataService.dataVisibility(this.data);
```

Object is received in `receiver` component and this is expected behaviour so I don't know why there is empty object in the application.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I didn't fully  understand the question can you elaborate a bit more please ? What you are trying to do ? what is the expected result? where the data is coming from ?

Comment: Trying to get object with data which is sent from component one to the service and trying to get these object in component two from the service using subscription. Always get empty object in component two, although in service object isn't empty.

Comment: Can you show the code where you implemented the Subject?

Comment: @Talg123 please take a look at the [subject.service] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kg4mg3). There is an implementation of the Behavior Subject and in the service (dataInfo) object is logged in the console.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour.

You are sending data from object-sender component on ngOnInit lifecycle`

```
export class ObjectSenderComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private shareDataService: ShareDataService) { }

    data: Object = {};

    ngOnInit() {
        this.shareDataService.dataVisibility(this.data);
    }

    onClick = () => {

        this.data = {
            dataName: "Data",
            dataVisible: true
        }

        this.shareDataService.dataVisibility(this.data);
    }
}
```

The component is added/removed to dom with async pipe`

```
 <app-receiver 
     *ngIf="shareDataService.isBtnClicked$ | async"
 ></app-receiver>
```

Thich means it will be destroyed and initialized every time you click on this button`

```
 <button (click)="onClick()"> Get Object </button>
```

And everytime ngOnInit lifecycle hook will be called. So everytime you remove the object-sender component from the dom and readd it, it will send this data;

```
data: Object = {};
```